# Using the Django admin for the Admin website

Tags: python, django

We have a project in which we have to use 3 different backend frameworks/programming language and integrate them together to form one correlated website: Java(Spring MVC) for the customer end website, PHP(CodeIgniter) for the service provider website, and Python(Django) for the admin site.

My question is, can I use the admin site of Django alone? I will only use it for accepting user registrations, deactivation, and tracking transactions. So it's all just going to be basic CRUD functions for the database. Or is there an alternative framework for me to use? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to define Models for the objects / tables used by other frameworks (which should be possible using Model Meta attributes to map it to an existing table name: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/).

The options you'll definitely want to use are db_table='*existing table name*' and managed=False (to tell Django not to prepare migrations for this table).

But as long as you can get a working Django Model that can interact with the tables for the other backends you should be able to read / update those records with the Admin interface just as if they were native Django models.